# Positive solutions to a PDE equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In this question I am concerned with **nonlinear positive harmonic solutions** to the following problem
$$Δu(x,y)=0, (x,y)∈(a,b)×ℝ$$
$$u(x,y)=0, (x,y)∈{a₀}×ℝ$$

where $a₀$ is a real constant in the interval $(a,b)$. i.e., find $u$ harmonic solution of that PDE such that $u>0$ or $u<0$ for all $(x,y)∈(a,a₀)×ℝ$. **Can we speak on the unicity, or some additional conditions are required**.

Comment: Is [the maximum principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_principle) relevant here?

Comment: what about $u(x,y)=x-a_0$? What is a harmonic solution? Simply a solution of the pde?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 : That certainly work. So does $y(x-a_0)$ and possibly a few others in that kind.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1: But I am looking for nonlinear functions.

Comment: @MarkMcClure: Formally, if $f$ is a harmonic function, then $f$ cannot exhibit a true local maximum within the domain of definition of $f$.

Comment: So probably, you checked the function $u(x,y)= (x-a_0)^2-y^2$ which fulfills the boundary data, but not the sign requirement on the cylinder $(a,a_0)\times \mathbb{R}$ , right?

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1: Ok, so, it is not a solution.

Comment: what about $u(x,y)=e^y \sin(x-a_0)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $c:=a_0-a >0$. For $n>0$ the functions
$$u_n(x,y):=exp\left(\frac{y}{cn}\right) \sin\left(\frac{x-a_0}{cn}\right)$$ are harmonic solutions to your problem. In particular, there is no uniqueness. (Of course, one could add some $\pi/2$ somewhere in here)